# How to solve React Native Firebase install error

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to set up Firebase in my React Native App, but it keeps failing to install.

Currently, I'm using

- Windows 10,
- Java SE (10.0.1)
- Node.js (8.11.3 LTS)
- Chocolately installed from website
- Android Studio
- Expo XDE
- Visual Studio Code

As for initial setting I have typed and installed once the followings,
- npm install -g react-native-cli
- npm install -g create-react-native-app
- Configured the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
 [Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrmZo.jpg)
 [Path Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/219zK.jpg)

The Steps I took to create a project is as below.

1. run Node.js command prompt in normal mode
2. type in "create-react-native-app MyNewProject1" to create a new project
3. npm install
4. npm install --save firebase
5. npm install --save react-navigation
6. run expo and open project
7. run emulator
8. Use expo to open project on android
9. Use Visual Studio Code to code
10. Code firebase by "import * as firebase from 'firebase';" 
    " firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)" etc. 
    also get ApiKey and all the information.

When the coding is complete. It keeps saying firebase is not installed.
And it keeps failing to install.
I even tried to install 'npm install firebase' or 'firebase-admin' 
but no use.

I even tried the instructions from the sites below.

- blog.benestudio.co/kickstart-your-react-native-app-with-firebase-tutorial-0-e6713bdb2012
- medium.com/@jamesmarino/getting-started-with-react-native-and-firebase-ab1f396db549
- firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

But none seems to install firebase.
It is not even in the dependencies.
Although navigations and other react native components do work.
Please help I've been stuck for a week.

Lastly, I also followed the steps that was instructed by the error given in Expo.
but it seems Node.js command prompt does not recognize how to follow orders as 'rm -rf node_modules && npm install' and the rest. Do anyone know how to run such commands?

-------------------------Error message from Expo below -------------------------

The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: ://packager.9g-4gd.eonlee.myproject7.exp.direct/node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=D%3A%5CReactNative%5Cmyproject7%5Cnode_modules%5Cexpo%5Ctools%5ChashAssetFiles

BodyX:
{"originModulePath":"D:\ReactNative\myproject7\LoginScreen.js","targetModuleName":"firebase","message":"Unable to resolve module `firebase` from `D:\\ReactNative\\myproject7\\LoginScreen.js`: Module `firebase` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `firebase` from `D:\\ReactNative\\myproject7\\LoginScreen.js`: Module `firebase` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `firebase` from `D:\\ReactNative\\myproject7\\LoginScreen.js`: Module `firebase` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)\n    at dependencies.map.relativePath (D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:376:19)\n    at Array.map (native)\n    at resolveDependencies (D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:374:16)\n    at D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:212:33\n    at Generator.next ()\n    at step (D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:297:313)\n    at D:\ReactNative\myproject7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:297:473"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:268
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:35
onChunkComplete
    BundleDownloader.java:195
emitChunk
    MultipartStreamReader.java:76
readAllParts
    MultipartStreamReader.java:154
processMultipartResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:179
access$100
    BundleDownloader.java:35
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:148
c
    RealCall.java:135
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
run

### Thread.java:818

Comment: You can use react-native-firebase it solves most of the errors if you do the process as shown in documentation step-by-step.
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved such issue by changing the main Directory of the saved folder.
When I create project in D drive it didn't allow me to install dependencies
I still don't know how to make the project work on D drive but 
when I moved the project folders to C drive or the main drive it started installing and worked.
Well I will just work on the main drive.